# How do I connect line bot to mqtt?

Tags: javascript, mqtt

I want to use line bot and mqtt to control the light. I want to send a message to line bot, then line bot will determine whether it is on or off. After that, line bot will send a command to mqtt, then it can control the light. The problem is that I can't connect line bot and mqtt successfully.

```
var CHANNEL_ACCESS_TOKEN = ' My LINE Channel Access Token ';

function doPost(e) {
     var replyToken = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents).events[0].replyToken;
     var userMessage = JSON.parse(e.postData.contents).events[0].message.text;


     if (userMessage.includes('Turn on')) {
          sendMqttCommandToBroker('My host', 'port', 'on');
          pushLineBotMessage('Turned on the light', replyToken);
     }
     else if (userMessage.includes('Turn off') {
          sendMqttCommandToBroker('My host', 'port', 'off');
          pushLineBotMessage('Turned off the light', replyToken);
     }
     return ContentService.createTextOutput('Received').setMimeType(ContentService.MimeType.TEXT);
}

function pushLineBotMessage(sMsg, sReplyToken){

     var linePayload = {
          'replyToken': sReplyToken,
          'messages': [
               {
                   'type': 'text',
                   'text': sMsg
               }
          ]
     };

     var lineOptions = {
          'method': 'post',
          'headers': {
               'Content-Type': 'application/json; charset=UTF-8',
               'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + CHANNEL_ACCESS_TOKEN
          },
          'payload': JSON.stringify(linePayload)
     };

     UrlFetchApp.fetch('https://api.line.me/v2/bot/message/reply', lineOptions);
}


function sendMqttCommandToBroker(mqttBrokerHost, mqttBrokerPort, mqttCommand) {

     var url = 'mqtt://' + mqttBrokerHost + ':' + mqttBrokerPort + '/TestMQTT_microbit'; // “TestMQTT_microbit” is my topic.
     var options = {
          'method': 'post',
          'payload': mqttCommand
     };
     try {
          var response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
          console.log('MQTT Command sent:', response.getContentText());
     } 
     catch (error) {
          console.error('Error sending MQTT command:', error);
     }
     // UrlFetchApp.fetch(url, options);
}
```

*In my code, I try to use this to connect line bot to mqtt, but it doesn't work...

Comment: ⟼Remember, it's always important, *especially* when learning and asking questions on Stack Overflow, to keep your code as organized as possible. [Consistent indentation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indentation_style) helps communicate structure and, importantly, intent, which helps us navigate quickly to the root of the problem without spending a lot of time trying to decode what's going on.

Comment: If your wanting to access MQTT via Browser / Node, then you might want to look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/mqtt  MQTT is not something that's built into node/browser so using fetch directly won't work.

Comment: Pardon my ignorance, but what is "line bot"?

Comment: Also 1) MQTT is not request response, it is async by design so you will need to change your way of thinking from HTTP. 2) If this is from the browser, then you will need to ensure the MQTT broker support MQTT over WebSockets as the client will not be able to connect.